# Missing generated file in doxygen docs

Tags: c++, doxygen

In my C++ development, I am making the documentation with Doxygen 1.8.13. Basically it works fine, but in some cases (sorry, I could not figure out why) a warning message

```
The file /Myhome/build/doc/inline_mscgraph_1.eps does not exist! Skipping it.
```

is received. Sometimes even two such messages, sometimes no such message.
As (at least intentionally) I do not want to create such a file, I presume that it should be generated by Doxygen. This is a warning when generating HTML docs, but error when creating CHM files. The .PDF also skips that missing file.

Why this file should be generated (I mean: in what circumstances), and if it should, why it is not generated? At least, how can I avoid this error situation?

It is probably not the dust of Doxygen, but related:
When I generate the .chm output, I receive messages such as

`Warning: Found file namespacestd.html while scanning Point_8h_source.html, but couldn't find it on disk`.

Where Point.h is really my header file, and really contains
"using namespace std;";
which I think this warning is related to. It is just an annoying warning, but I receive tons of such messages, and makes it hard to notice the more meaningful warnings. Any idea how to get rid of them?

**Edit:**
With the original question, it looks like something is wrong with handling the \msc command. (the source was compiled successfully a couple of months ago; sorry I did not remember the version)

Here I show my code fragment:

```
\msc "Transferring a message using proxy"
arcgradient = 8;
  s[label="Source A"], p[label="Proxy B"], d[label="Dest C"];
  s=>p [label="M1", ID="Original"];
  p=>d [label="M2", ID="Proxied"];
\endmsc
```

If that code is present in my '.dox' file, I receive the message about the missing .eps file; and the entire '.dox' file is canceled from the compilation.

I noticed one more issue with the new version. In my source I have

```
@page BASE_Technical_Guide   Technical Guide

        @section TECHNICAL_GUIDE_TABLE_OF_CONTENTS Table of contents
        -# @subpage Technical_Guide_Introduction_Page
        -# @subpage Technical_Guide_Other_Page
```

That code, in the previous version, compiled to a clickable TOC, now it is displayed as text between @code @endcode

And finally, an issue for all versions:
When compiling latex/pdf docs, I receive tons of "underfull" messages. I understand that the automatic generation cannot be beautified, but could you please consider adding a line to the output to suppress those messages? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99274/how-to-suppress-underfull-vbox-warning-for-one-specific-marginpar

**And a last remark, for the maintainers of the site**: I am warned by Grammarly to fix the mistypes. However, if I accept what Grammarly proposes, it appears as accepted in the source, but not in the preview.

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.13 is from December 2016, the current version is 1.8.18. What happens when you use the newer version (I remember that in the past there were some problems with a.o. namespace files).

Comment: My Ubunbu said "doxygen is already the newest version (1.8.13-10)". OK, I will try to upgrade.

Comment: Sorry, not quite this line, but after changing the conan.txt file, the status isdoxygen_installer/1.8.15@bincrafters/stable, but the installed version remains 1.8.13

Comment: OK. I successfully installed the new version. The missing namespace error gone, the missing file persists. Also, I noticed that the new check introduced (notice the missing  't') "from the argument list of .. has muliple @param documentation sections".

Comment: The different distributions quite often a bit behind with providing new versions (and even doxygen doesn't release that often). An alternative would be to download the 1.8.18 source code (or the master version from github) and compile it yourself. In the 1.8.18 version the missing 't' has been fixed as well.

Comment: You may be interested in the result of the quiz: I used in one of my files '\msc["Transferring a message using proxy"]', without quotation in the caption. This leads to no error message/warning, but prevents making the .eps file, and it is missed in a later phase. Thanks for your hints.

Comment: You are referring  to the syntax `\msc ["caption"] [<sizeindication>=<size>]`  where in the Caption was in your case multiple words, but you didn't place the double quotes? Note that the `[` and `]` are in the description the usual placeholders for "optional argument" (see description in the documentation , http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.htmlfort the general description of `[` and `]`, a bit hidden and http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdmsc for the description of `\msc`)

Comment: @ albert In my files, I have a kind of table of contents on pages, in form
       \section TECHNICAL_GUIDE_TABLE_OF_CONTENTS Table of contents
        -# \subpage Technical_Guide_Introduction_Page
        -# \subpage Technical_Guide_Other_Page
In the previous version, it was compiled to a clickable TOC;
in the 1.8.15 it is compiled to simply that text between \code \encode
If this change is intentional, what is the new syntax?

Comment: @ albert Surely, I know [] is a usual placeholder, I just made a careless copy/paste mistake. I just mentioned it for your debugging. My careless writing enables to generate a hard-to-find error

Comment: @ albert This new version also makes a new style of formatting: as (probably) the TOC nature of my source is misinterpreted, the "related pages" page is not any more indented, and not more section/subsection exist. Probably it is not the intended behavior.

Comment: Based on just some comments it is hard to get the exact problems. In case of problems edit it into the original question or in case of new problems open a new question.

Comment: I see in the edit: 1) about the `\msc`, looks like doxygen doesn't like it `dox` file when it is not inside a sectioning command, when adding `\page` it looks like it is working. 2) Indentation, this is due to how Markdown interprets leading spaces (similar to stack overflow, indentation by an extra 4 or more spaces mean code), this is different from 1.8.13 version. 3) Underflow, are indeed a bit of a nuisance but the are hard to remove as where to put the limit. You can always add it in an extra (style type) file so you can choose your own value. 4) the remark about Grammerly I don't get it